# sql selection from two tables

Tags: sql, select

i have two tables DETAILS and BANLIST. i search DETAILS table to get list of IPs:

```
select ip, time, othecol from details WHERE somefield=X
```

as a result i get zero or N records.
at the same time i need to know if returned IP is banned or not. I can check it like this:

```
select isbanned from banlist WHERE ip=someIP
```

is it possible to combine both statements in one?

to get a list in format:| ip, time, othercol, isbanned |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_join):

```
SELECT d.ip, d.time, d.othercol, b.isbanned FROM details d
LEFT JOIN banlist b on b.ip = d.ip
WHERE d.somefield=X
```

Note, `b.isbanned` will be `null` for rows in `details` that have no matching IP in `banlist`.  You can [coalesce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#COALESCE) that value into a false (the syntax for this varies based on what RDMS you're using.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do a simple join

```
SELECT d.ip, b.isbanned
FROM details d
LEFT JOIN banlist b  ON d.ip = b.ip
WHERE foo=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [INNER JOIN keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) for SQL.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```